# Can I use global variables in myapp.views.py to store data of different users in a django web application?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to design a web application in django in which a user uploads an exel sheet, some calculation will be done and user can view the calculted results filtered by a set of radio buttons. The end results are temporary and can be deleted as soon as the user logs out. So I am using only two templates one for sign in and one for my main page where I can upload file and view results.
I am saving the end results as a dictionary of dictionaries as a global variable in myapp.views.py. Do I need to use a database for my requirement ? Also when multiple users sign in , I am thinking of saving the data as a global dictionary where key is username and value is end results for that user. Is this method correct?
Is there any better way to fulfill my requirement ? When does the global variables in myapp.views.py will ceases to exist ?
Sorry for the long explanation

Answer (score 0):

No, you should never do this. Apart from anything else, in a production setting your site will definitely served by more than one process, and a global dictionary is not shared between processes.

The place to store temporary information between requests is the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: For each user, I have a dictionary user_info which has several objects of class MyClass. Can I save this dictionary in a session? Sorry if my question is weird I am a bit new to web application development